# Match height with 100% width

Tags: html, css, image

I am adding a few images to a portfolio website but want to use background-image in oppose to the img property. The website is very responsive and uses percents for it's basic structure. I am using the background-img property and setting the width of the container to 100% of its parent. Adding a set height makes the image visible however adding height:100% or height:auto makes the image disappear, I'm sure this is probably a pretty simple piece of code to figure out but I can't seem to find a solution. Below is the code I am using to implement the image

```
.image-left {
    float:left;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-image:url(/img/image.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

And here is a http://jsfiddle.net/WD4HM/3/ to better explain my problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: 100%` does not work unless the parent element has an explicit height. The reason the image is disappearing when you use this rule is because the element actually has *no* height.

However, you can use javascript to capture the window height, and then match the element you want to be 100% of the window height.

Comment: I want to avoid Javascript for things like this as they are going to be happening a lot all over the website. I may have to settle for the img tag. Thanks for the help @JakeParis

Answer (score 0):

new answer:

```
#wrap {
 width:50%; 
 margin:0 auto; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 background:blue;
}
.img-left {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%; 
 background-image:url(tiger.jpg);
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: 100% 100%; 
 margin-bottom:45px;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, let me knock up a jsfiddle to explain my problem a little better. @Don Kelley

Comment: I can make the image appear and resize dynamically as I play with the window in safari on my mac with some changes to your css.  The photo's aspect ratio changes too (and change url back to your own tiger picture... change your margins/padding back also as desired).... is this anything like what you're looking to do?
Take a look at my edited answer above and we'll keep working from there.